# Getting this menu to stay open after link click

Tags: menu, slide

I have tried several things but cant get this slide menu to stay open. Any thoughts???

```
$(function() {
$('.items ul').hide();
});

$('.1979').click(function() {
$(this).find('.entries').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/johnrsherwood/u6bnra9x/12/

Comment: what do you mean to stay open?

Comment: when a link is clicked, the menu closes. id like it to stay open...